# SqlCommand for Ior filling values to ComboBox from multiple columns

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, combobox, sqlcommand

Hello friends I have column cena1, cena2, cena3 and I need to display it's values in combobox, is there any way to do that? 
I tried this:

```
 spojeni.Open();
 var cb4 = new SqlCommand("SELECT cena1,cena2,cena3 FROM zajezd WHERE akce="+zakce.Text,spojeni);

            SqlDataReader dr4 = cb4.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr4.Read())
            {
                comboBox4.Items.Add(dr4["cena1,cena2,cena3"]);


            }
            dr4.Close();
            dr4.Dispose();
```

But the program falls. Would you please help me ?

```
            spojeni.Close();
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: **How** does it fail? Do you get an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
spojeni.Open();
var cb4 = new SqlCommand("SELECT cena1,cena2,cena3 FROM zajezd WHERE akce="+zakce.Text,spojeni);

        SqlDataReader dr4 = cb4.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr4.Read())
        {
            comboBox4.Items.Add(dr4["cena1"].ToString() + dr4["cena2"].ToString() + dr4["cena3"].ToString());


        }
        dr4.Close();
        dr4.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change those column values into rows by using Pivots. Here is a [tutorial](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/06/07/sql-server-pivot-and-unpivot-table-examples/) to use Pivot clause. Or you can use union since its only 3 columns. But I would recommend using pivot.

Example:

```
  select cena 
  from (
  select akce, cena1 cena from zajezd
  union all
  select akce, cena2 cena  from zajezd
  union all
  select akce, cena3 cena  from zajezd
  ) t
  where
     t.akce =
```

And in C# you can specify the column name as cena

Example:

```
  comboBox4.Items.Add(dr4["cena"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a valid way to retreive the column value

```
dr4["cena1,cena2,cena3"]
```

The correct way to use it like this

```
string val1 = Convert.ToString(dr4["cena1"]);
string val2 = Convert.ToString(dr["cena2"]);
string val3 = Convert.ToString(dr["cena3"]);
comboBox4.Items.Add(val1+" " +val2+" " +val3);
```

And you should also use parameterized query to avoid sql injection.

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
comboBox4.Items.Add(dr4["cena1,cena2,cena3"]);
```

to

```
comboBox4.Items.Add(dr4["cena1"]);

comboBox4.Items.Add(dr4["cena2"]);

comboBox4.Items.Add(dr4["cena3"]);
```

Your code is vulnerablle to Sqlinjection. Although you may consider reading [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) for information on Sql injection